# How to check data in cloudapp?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, sqlclient

I am working on existing project I am aware about Mysql database connections to the projects. But in this project I found Following connection string in web config

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/testDB.csdl|res://*/testDB.ssdl|res://*/testDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=test.cloudapp.net,57410;initial catalog=test2uat;persist security info=True;user id=test2uat;password=*******;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am not aware of this type of data source,  what is cloudapp.net in datasource and csdl,ssdl and msl. and how can i check existing data of the project ?

Thanks for the Help !

Comment: can i ask,, existing project from what language?android?

Comment: @reds not a android project, It is MVC project (C#)